# Ошибка QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qmainwindow

Пытаюсь форму созданную в *Qt Designer* загрузить в приложение.

Код ниже выдаёт ошибку:

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Как её исправить?

---

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout,QMessageBox)

import sys
import mydesign

with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file: 
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}

win = uic.loadUi("C:/mydesign.ui")

class SignInWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        loginbutton.clicked.connect(self.check)

    def check(self):
        uname = self.usernameline.text()
        pword=  self.passwordline.text()
        if uname in users and users[uname] == pword:
            self.label.setText("Welcome back")
        else:
            self.label.setText("No user with username/password has been been found")
            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    si = SignInWindow()
    si.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout,QMessageBox)

import sys
import mydesign

with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file: 
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}

# win = uic.loadUi("C:/mydesign.ui")              # ---

class SignInWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi("C:/mydesign.ui", self)               # +++

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        loginbutton.clicked.connect(self.check)

    def check(self):
        uname = self.usernameline.text()
        pword=  self.passwordline.text()
        if uname in users and users[uname] == pword:
            self.label.setText("Welcome back")
        else:
            self.label.setText("No user with username/password has been been found")
            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    si = SignInWindow()
    si.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update**

> Выдаёт ошибку Traceback (most recent call last): TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class 'main.SignInWindow'>, 'QMainWindow'))

замените `class SignInWindow(QWidget):` на  `class SignInWindow(QMainWindow):`

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class '__main__.SignInWindow'>, 'QMainWindow'))

Comment: name 'QMainWindow' is not defined

Comment: @jeremygreenwoods   добавьте в импорты `QMainWindow`.  `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow`